# c++ method parameters giving unexpected output

Tags: c++

Main class code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Chair.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
Chair c1;
c1.chairType("Olivia",4,32,true);       // not working
Chair c2;
c1.chairType("Stephano",8,8,false);
return 0;
}
```

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Header class code:

#ifndef CHAIR_H_INCLUDED
#define CHAIR_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Chair
{
private:
    int legCount;
    int height;
    bool cushioned;
    string name;
public:
    void chairType(string newName, int newLegCount, int newHeight, bool cush);


};



#endif // CHAIR_H_INCLUDED
```

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Chair.cpp class:


#include <iostream>
#include "Chair.h"

using namespace std;

void Chair::chairType(string newName, int newLegCount, int newHeight, bool cush)
{
    name=newName;
    legCount=newLegCount;
    newHeight=newHeight;
    cushioned=cush;

    cout<<"I'm a chair, the following are my specs: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Model: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Num of Legs: "<<legCount<<endl;
    cout<<"Height: "<<height<<endl;
    cout<<"Cushioned? : "<<cush<<endl;
}
```

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Output for the four variables fed into the method is as expected, apart from the third variable (second int) which is printing as being 2752192 regardless of what I feed to it, and for both objects c1 and c2.

I'm new to C++. I've been practising some object class questions trying to familiarise myself with the syntax. I vaguely understand pointers can cause reference addresses to print on occasion. However, this 7 digit number doesn't appear to be in address format. I've done some searches and can't see a similar question. If there is one, I would appreciate direction to it. I don't wish to break the terms of posting here on the site. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Voting to close since the problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newHeight=newHeight;
```

should be replaced with

```
height=newHeight;
```

but better you should initialize object in constructor, rather than separate method:

```
class Chair
{
private:
    int legCount;
    int height;
    bool cushioned;
    string name;
public:
    Chair( const string &newName, int newLegCount, int newHeight, bool cush) :
        legCount( newLegCount ),
        height( newHeight ),
        cushioned( cush ),
        name( newName )
    {
    }
    ...
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    Chair c1("Olivia",4,32,true);       // works now
    Chair c2("Stephano",8,8,false);
    return 0;
}
```

this way you cannot have instance of your class uninitialized and your mistake also would be detected by compiler.

Comment: Unrelated to OP's question , but it's simpler and more efficient to have the constructor take `string newName` instead of `const string &newName`. This means that if called with an rvalue, the contents can be moved into `newName`, instead of being copied and then the original destructed.

Comment: @M.M I  doubt that would be more efficient. yes content can be moved to `newName` in that case, but `newName` will be copied to `name`.

Comment: sorry, also use `name(std::move(newName))`

Comment: @M.M ok, but is there a verifiable data of efficiency improving, or it is pure theoretical?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty confident this could be demonstrated by an example, although I haven't actually done it. You'd think that one allocation is faster than two allocations and one free, even if not by much.

Comment: @M.M I think it would be a good question to put on SO, if it does not already exist. I do not think, that one allocation is not faster than two, I doubt there would be 2 allocations with const reference after optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake in your implementation *Chair.cpp*:
    `newHeight=newHeight;`

This is the correct:
    `height = newHeight;`

The long number you get is the uninitialized value of member variable `height` in your `Chair` object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: no problem and no inconvenience - we have learnt programming the same way - asking, trying, asking, trying...